# SPARQL querie not returning some classes

Tags: sparql

Hi I'm doing an ontology in order to describe some aspects of a University as an organization.
I'm running queries locally with sparql about all classes at first and while some classes show up others don't. I've used some IRI's from dpbedia and I've put rdf:isDefinedBy for dpbedia and
for our ontologies name. Here's the Sparql querie of all 6 of the classes that don't show up.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX SOS: <https://teliki.ergasia.pc/SOS#>
Select ?Organization ?Program ?Person ?Scholar ?Gender ?Human_settlement
WHERE { ?Organization a SOS:Organization.
          ?Program a SOS:Program.
              ?Person a SOS:Person.
     ?Scholar a SOS:Scholar.
   ?Gender a SOS:Gender.
 ?Human_settlement a SOS:Human_settlement. }
```

And here's an ss of classes and subclasses.
[SOS classes and subclasses][1]

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u5Qg.png
```

Update:
I only intended to retrieve the individuals of each class,which turns out I can do now since I've changed the IRI's to the ones of my ontology rather than that of dbpedia. My current problem is that I can't get to select a subset of a class's individuals according to an object property as it only returns a blank space. Heres the code:

```
PREFIX SOS: <https://teliki.ergasia.pc/SOS#>
Select ?Teach_s 
WHERE { ?Teach_s a SOS:Teaching_staff.
?Teach_s SOS:has_Gender "Male". }
```

Comment: I don't get what your query is supposed to return. So far there is no connection between any triple pattern - this results in a cartesian product of all instances of each class. What is the purpose of this query? Each triple pattern does bind the individuals of each class to the corresponding variable. Are there any instances for each class in your data? What is the current result of your query?

Comment: is there such a data property in your ontology? What is the datatype of the literal? Please try to query with datatype, i.e. `?Teach_s SOS:has_Gender "Male"^^xsd:string` or whatever you assigned as datatype to the gender fact literals

Comment: has_Gender is an object property with Person as a domain and Gender as a range, Gender beeing a class and "Male"/"Female beeing an individual of Gender. Is there a way to filter by object  properties rather than data properties?

Comment: if it is an object property, why do you query for a string literal? I mean, then you have to use the URI of the gender, not a plain string literal like `"male"` - it should be something like `?Teach_s SOS:has_Gender SOS:male.` then, or whatever the URI of the gender male is

Comment: Yup, that seems to work. Silly me.